# Procurar por items similares ao usar uma tabela de intermediação?

Tags: mysql, select, lógica

Seguindo alguns conselhos para optimizar as queries em MySQL, decidi dividir uma lista de items em 3 tabelas:

Tabela animes:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id             | titulo      |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | Anime A     |
+----------------+-------------+
| 2              | Anime B     |
+----------------+-------------+
| 3              | Anime C     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Tabela de generos:

```
+----------------+-------------+
| id             | genero      |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | Ação        |
+----------------+-------------+
| 2              | Romance     |
+----------------+-------------+
| 3              | Ninja       |
+----------------+-------------+
```

E então uma terceira tabela usada para fazer a ligação entre a tabela de animes e a tabela de generos, definindo a qual genero cada anime pertence.

```
+----------------+-------------+
| anime_id       | genero_id   |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | 1           |
+----------------+-------------+
| 1              | 3           |
+----------------+-------------+
| 2              | 2           |
+----------------+-------------+
| 2              | 3           |
+----------------+-------------+
| 3              | 2           |
+----------------+-------------+
```

Dado o ID de um anime, eu consigo pegar suas categorias usando a seguinte query:

```
SELECT an.id, an.titulo, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genero) AS generos
    FROM animes an 

    INNER JOIN tabela_intermediacao ti ON ti.anime_id = an.id

    INNER JOIN generos g ON g.id = ti.genero_id

WHERE an.id = 1
```

Até o presente momento não tive dificuldades, porém e se eu quisesse obter os animes similares ao anime 1 por exemplo, ordenando-os com base na quantidade de gêneros em comum que eles têm, como construir essa query, de preferência que seja na mesma query que eu mostrei antes, se não for possível estou aberto a uma query separada só para pegar os similares;

[Exemplo Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c7f9a/1)

Comment: Você terá que fazer uma subquery com count. Posta um fiddle, já ajuda nós montarmos e testarmos "no seu ambiente".

Comment: @RBZ acabei de adicionar a pergunta o fiddle

Comment: @RBZ poderias também mostrar como retornar somente os similares? Ao invés de retornar o próprio anime usado como base para a pesquisa?

Comment: Postado como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Funciona dessa forma, mas assim que puder vejo outras.*

Ao meu ver, não tem como fazer sem ser por **subquery**.
Então filtrei e separei todos os animes e seus gêneros, e os `generos`, filtrei por uma **subquery** que trás os gêneros do anime filtrado:

```
SELECT an.id, an.titulo, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genero) AS generos
FROM animes an
INNER JOIN anime_genero ti ON ti.anime_id = an.id
INNER JOIN generos g ON g.id = ti.genero_id
GROUP BY an.id
HAVING generos = (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(g.genero) AS generos
FROM animes an
INNER JOIN anime_genero ti ON ti.anime_id = an.id
INNER JOIN generos g ON g.id = ti.genero_id
WHERE an.id = 1
)
```

Exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8639cb/5)

Comment: Parece funcionar bem :) é possível fazer com que o retorno não contenha o anime usado como base para a pesquisa? Ou seja não vir o anime 1 mas só os seus similares

Comment: Sim. Adicione `WHERE an.id <> 1` antes do `GROUP BY an.id`. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8639cb/9)